# CocoaTouch framework with resources

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, resourcebundle

I am building a framework in which it uses some image files and `.xib` files. Now I am building framework and a bundle separately and distributing this `.framework` and `.bundle` to other developers. New what I need to do is need to distribute this framework and bundle together. Is there any way to build framework and bundle together and distribute as a single package.

For creating framework I am using shell script in with it creates `.a` file for simulator and device then combine together using `lipo` tool.

I need to access these resources these reources from inside the framework code as well as from outside framework code. Right now I am accessing resources like,

```
NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyFrameworkBundle" withExtension:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundleURL];
NSString *path = [resourceBundle pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"extension"];
```

How to tackle this?. Is it a good method that keeping resources inside framework?